# Missing Files in Drupal 7 on OpenShift

Tags: drupal-7, openshift

I have a drupal installation running on OpenShift. I have been installing all modules and themes using git (commandline). However, I attempted to install the modules directly and the installation worked.
The problem that I now face is that when I attempt a pull request all I get is the modules and themes I had installed using the commandine and not the ones that I installed 'directly'.

Any one with a heads up on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kraman above I got a hint of what to do.

I ran `rhc snapshot save -a appname` and got all the files. At least I know where to start off from since I can access the files.

A word of caution though for drupal users on openshift, just use git or sftp for pushing files and save yourself the headache.

Comment: Did you commit with git the file you get with rhc snapshit save -a appname ?

Answer (score 2):

OpenShift runs your code form a checkout of the git repository located at `~/app-root/repo` within your gear. When you upload files using Drupal (instead of the git repository), the modules and themes are installed in this checked out directory and are not tracked in git.
I you are using a scaled application, I would recommend that copy the modules/themes and check them into git instead of the Drupal install method.

For now, to retrieve all your files you can try the `rhc export` command.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That saved my skin. Pointed me in the right direction.